# How to check port 8080 in Windows Vista command prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am very new to programming and setting up Java Servers. Actually its my first time to try it but not successful. I am about to test my first web app in Java but whenever I click the  "Start server in debug mode" button in Eclipse I am always having error about my Tomcat server saying that port 8080 is being used. I wanna know how am I gonna check it in the console and close it if possible. Do you know other ways on dealing with this??? I also tried netstat but can't find the port 8080 among the list. Please help me out because I am really getting frustrated. I a tried whatever solution I find in google but still having the same problem. If you can explain to me what's going on that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/35218/in-windows-using-the-command-line-how-do-you-check-if-a-port-is-open

Answer (score 19):

Use the following command:

```
netstat -an | find ":8080"
```

to check whether the port 8080 is open.

Comment: Nothing means the port is NOT being listened ( not in use ). Try to telnet <your IP> 8080

Comment: I tried telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 but it says telnet is not a recognized batch command... I am sorry I am very new to this thing... Can you explain it to me... Please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: install telnet first from Add/Remove Programs, or download PuTTY from Internet.

Answer (score 3):

try using the following `command:  \> netstat -a`