# How do I find which application is using up my port?

Tags: windows, port, windows-vista, netstat

I am unable to start GlassFish, because it keeps showing this error message:

```
SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port within range: 8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@ed7d1
```

How can I find what applications are using what ports on Windows Vista?
I have tried using nmap zenmap using the following target:

http://127.0.0.1:8080

But all I get is this:

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-08-05 12:05 Central Daylight Time

NSE: Loaded 57 scripts for scanning.

Read data files from: C:\Program Files\Nmap
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 4.55 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 0 (0B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B)
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check port 8080 in Windows Vista command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606612/how-to-check-port-8080-in-windows-vista-command-prompt)

Comment: This saved my day, yet it belongs to superuser.com, I wish there was a way to move questions betwen stackexchange sites

Comment: While developing web services in VS 2017 in C#, this question/answer stopped me from rebooting my computer every 2 hours ... while it is not directly relevant to programming, it is indirectly extremely helpful to all of us developing sockets.

Comment: So you are looking which application is using port 8080?
First, enter this command in cmd .....

netstat -ano | findstr :8080

this or similar you will see

TCP  0.0.0.0:8080  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING  4492

now you know the id of application which using port 8080
then find that app using id
type in this code with your id, (in my case it 4492)
 
tasklist | findstr 4492
 and here you go.
 Tomcat9.exe   4492 Services  0 77.988 K

Answer (score 120, accepted):

How about netstat?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980

The command is `netstat -anob`.

(Make sure you run command as admin)

I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -anob
```

Active Connections

```
     Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP           0.0.0.0:80                0.0.0.0:0                LISTENING         4
 Can not obtain ownership information

  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       692
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]

  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7540
 [Skype.exe]

  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       564
 [LMS.exe]

  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4480
 [vmware-authd.exe]
```

And If you want to check for the particular port, command to use is:
*netstat -aon | findstr 8080*
from the same path

Comment: did netstat -anob | findstr "8080", it gave me the task id, It would be nice though to know, which application is using it from the PID, is there a command to do this? btw: not through the task manager, I hate having to search through that list

Comment: You can use `tasklist` command to see list of all running processes with their PID.

Comment: question marked off topic but this answer saved my day, i found the cuprit using 8099! Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me but after using `taskkill /pid 8516`, I got `ERROR: The process "8516" not found.` Turns out if a child process is running, Windows will keep the socket around. Killing the child process freed the socket. http://serverfault.com/questions/181015/how-do-you-free-up-a-port-being-held-open-by-dead-process

Comment: In my case Oracle TNS Listener was the culprit:tasklist | findstr "5676"
TNSLSNR.EXE                   5676 Services                   0      5,140 K

Answer (score 10):

To see which ports are available on your machine run:

```
C:>  netstat -an |find /i "listening"
```

Answer (score 7):

It may be possible that there is no other application running. It is possible that the socket wasn't cleanly shutdown from a previous session in which case you may have to wait for a while before the TIME_WAIT expires on that socket. Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the port till that socket expires. If you can start your server after waiting for a while (a few minutes) then the problem is not due to some other application running on port 8080.

Answer (score 3):

On the command prompt, do:

```
netstat -nb
```

Comment: Not working it is throwing me an error saying "The requested operation requires elevation."

Comment: @SohailQureshi Just run the Command Prompt as an Administrator.