# Tomcat 8.5 fails connection to localhost/8080

Tags: apache, jsp, server, tomcat8

I am running Apache Tomcat 8.5. After I start tomcat, I enter the address `http://localhost/8080/` in the browser address bar but it gives me the following error :

[image: Tomcat error]

How do I solve this error and get tomcat running normally ?

Comment: Please try browsing to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

The link(url) http://localhost/8080/ you are using to access the tomcat page is wrong.

It should be http://localhost:8080. Please try.

Comment: Using http://localhost:8080 gives me an error "This site can't be reached" even though my internet is working fine.

Comment: @iammrmehul : There are multiple points to be checked. U need to see if there is any other application is running on the same port 8080 . If you have oracle database installed it runs on 8080 port. Also in your tomcat conf folder you will have a file called server.xml. In that file check the entry for the following     <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: See what is the value of Connector port="" . Check whether it is 8080 or it has some other value. If it has some other value then you need to access it as follows http://localhost:portnumber

Comment: Also there are multiple links to the same problem. Please check them. The following are the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021136/tomcat-starts-but-home-page-cannot-open-with-url-http-localhost8080

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086242/cannot-open-http-localhost8080-when-tomcat-is-running-in-eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189217/my-tomcat-is-running-but-i-cant-connect-to-http-localhost8080