# React native ERROR Packager can't listen on port 8081

Tags: react-native

When I run command `react-native start`, it shows `Packager can't listen on port 8081`.

I know the issue is about software using my port 8081 .

I use Resource Monitor to see the port, but I can't find 8081, there is no 8081

Can someone show me how to find it?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960019/how-do-i-find-which-application-is-using-up-my-port), you should find it.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, make sure the Metro bundler isn't already running in some long forgotten terminal Window somwhere.

Comment: Refer : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200727/reactnative-port-8081-issue-403-forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200727/reactnative-port-8081-issue-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can run the packager on another port.

```
$ react-native start --port=8088
```

Alternatively, find out what is using which ports on Windows with netstat.

```
$ netstat -a -b -o
```

Netstat gives you a PID, which you can use to kill the process.

```
$ taskkill /pid 1234
```

Answer (score 180):

On a mac, run the following command to find id of the process which is using port `8081`
`sudo lsof -i :8081`
Then run the following to terminate process:
`kill -9 23583`

Here is how it will look like
[image]

Comment: Works on ubuntu 18.04 also

Comment: Worked for me as well, on MacOS High Sierra

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS Big Sur, too

Answer (score 36):

This error is coming because some process is already running on 8081 port. Stop that process and then run your command, it will run your code. For this first list all the process which are using this port by typing

```
lsof -i :8081
```

This command will list the process id (PID) of the process and then kill the node process by using

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Here PID is the process id of the node process.

Answer (score 22):

That picture indeed shows that your 8081 is not in use. If suggestions above haven't helped, and your mobile device is connected to your computer via usb (and you have Android 5.0 (Lollipop) or above) you could try:

```
$ adb reconnect
```

This is not necessary in most cases, but just in case, let's reset your connection with your mobile and restart adb server. Finally:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

So, whenever your mobile device tries to access any port 8081 on itself it will be routed to the 8081 port on your PC.

Or, one could try

```
$ killall node
```

Answer (score 13):

> **Ubuntu/Unix** && **MacOS**

My Metro Bundler was stuck and there were lots of node processes running but I didn't have any other development going on besides react-native, so I ran:

```
$ killall -9 node
```

The Metro Bundler is running through node on port 8081 by default, and it can encounter issues sometimes whereby it gets stuck (usually due to pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in rapid succession with hot reloading on). If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill the `react-native run-android` process, you will suddenly have a bad time because `react-native-run-android` will get stuck on :

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/poop/dev/some-app/node_modules (41ms)
```

Fix:

```
$ killall -9 node

$ react-native run-android
```

**Note:** if you are developing other apps at the time, killing all the node proceses may interrupt them or any node-based services you have running, so be mindful of the sweeping nature of `killall -9`. If you aren't running a node-based database or app or you don't mind manually restarting them, then you should be good to go.

The reason I leave this detailed answer on this semi-unrelated question is that mine is a solution to a common semi-related problem that sadly requires 2 steps to fix but luckily only takes 2 steps get back to work.

If you want to surgically remove exactly the Metro Bundler garbage on port 8081, do the steps in the answer from **RC_02**, which are:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8081

$ kill -9 23583
```

(where 23583 is the process ID)

Answer (score 7):

You should kill all the processes running on port 8081 by `kill -9 $(lsof -i:8081)`

Answer (score 6):

Take the terminal and type

```
fuser 8081/tcp
```

You will get a Process id which is using port 8081
Now kill the process

```
kill <pid>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a chance for running programs on port 8081. If you install McAfee antivirus then it's agent will be running on port 8081. So, We can't use the same for other programs.

First we have to verify that the port 8081 is listening or not.

**In Windows,**

Open CMD and run the command to check whether any program running on the port 8081.

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8081
```

Assume that if you got output something like this,

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5800
```

Then kill the program with ID 5800 using the following command,

```
taskkill /pid 5800
```

**In Linux / Mac,**

Open terminal and run the command to check whether any program running on the port 8081.

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
```

Assume that if you got output something like this,

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node     59 root   18u  IPv4 609033      0t0  TCP localhost:8081 (LISTEN)
```

Then kill the program with ID 609033 using the following command,

```
sudo kill -9 59
```

**Alternatively,
You can also run the packager on another port.**

```
react-native start --port=8088
react-native run-android --port=8088
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is already a Node server running on your machine and then close it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run in another port like 3131. Run the command:

```
react-native run-android --port=3131
```

Comment: McAfee is using this port in my case. As mentioned, running in different port helps.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because of McAfee using that port. 
Doing simple `lsof -i 8081` may not show the application and you may have to sudo it.

Do `sudo lsof -i 8081` and if this command gives an output you can kill it by using
`sudo launchctl remove com.mcafee.agent.macmn`. After this start packager again.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, internet on emulator is down as there is no wifi signal on emulator. Resetting emulator has worked.

Answer (score 1):

just write in terminal

```
killall -9 node
```

Then restart your project with npm start your error will be solve

Comment: THe answer is already there. didn't see any improvements in the pervious answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, the process I have mentioned below.

Please cancel the current process of“react-native run-android” by CTRL + C or CMD + C

**Close metro bundler(terminal) window command line which opened automatically.**

**Run the command again on terminal, “react-native run-android**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your device go to **Dev. Option -> ADB over Network**
after do it:

```
$ adb connect <your device adb network>
$ react-native run-android
```

(or run-ios, by the way)

if this has successfully your device has installed app-debug.apk,
open app-debug and go to **Dev. Settings -> Debug server host & port for device**,
type in your machine's IP address (generally, **System preference -> Network**), as in the example below < **your machine's IP address** >**:8081** (whihout inequality)

finally, execute the command below

```
$ react-native start --port=8081
```

try another ports, and verify that you machine and your device are same network.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

Open **PowerShell** and **Run as Administrator**:

1. `net stop winnat`

> The Windows NAT Driver service was stopped successfully.

2. `net start winnat`

> The Windows NAT Driver service was started successfully.

[EVD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv3ej.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by cleaning my Gradle cache.
Using this command:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```