# ReactNative Metro Bundler not starting automatically

Tags: android, react-native

`react-native run-android` not starting bundler so i tried
`react-native start` it showing below error.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1286:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1421:7)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Prasanth/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:157:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Prasanth/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:156:12)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/user/Documents/Prasanth/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:47:262)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Prasanth/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:47:422
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Server.WebSocketServer._onServerError (/Users/user/Documents/Prasanth/AwesomeProject/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:82:50)
    at Server.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**react-native info**

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz
      Memory: 3.36 GB / 12.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
      Android SDK:
        Build Tools: 21.1.2, 23.0.1, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
        API Levels: 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
      react-native: 0.57.2 => 0.57.2 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I tried cleaning cache and reverse adb still am getting that issue

`react-native run-android` showing below error.

[image]

**Android Home** configuration

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<Path>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: The thrown error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081` means that there is already something listening on the port 8081. Did you check wether something is listening on that port f.e. with `netstat -a | grep LISTEN` or `lsof -i :8081`?

Comment: @makadev above command returns
tcp4       0      0  localhost.51565        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.51133                *.*  makadev                  LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  localhost.5037         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.49162                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN

Comment: tcp4       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.sunproxyadmin        *.*                    LISTEN

Comment: The `.sunproxyadmin` is the service descriptor for port 8081, so there is something listening there. Check your Terminals, there might be another Metrobuilder instance running (f.e. Xcode running the App?).To kill whatever process is running on that port and if you have `lsof` or `brew` for installing it, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47820483/3828957.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I tried following steps it resolves my issue

1. Running packager on different port `react-native start --port 8084 --reset-cache`
2. Run `react-native run-android --port 8084` in second Command Prompt window.
3. After error screen appear clicking **Android** `Ctrl + M`, **iOS** `Command + D`.
4. Click Dev Settings button at the bottom.
5. Click Debug server host & port for device button.
6. Type `localhost:8084` and click OK button.
7. Again run `react-native run-android --port 8084`

Comment: Can please state some steps for ios

Answer (score 20):

Replace the code with this one. The path of the file is -

> node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

I found this solution from Github.

Comment: I can't believe this is what worked for me, but it is. RN 0.63.4

Comment: @Ajoy Karmakar I don't have a `blacklist.js` file there, what version of metro are you on?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it'll be overwritten any time `node_modules`, which aren't saved to your remote repo, are reinstalled. During active development, I reinstall `node_modules` multiple times per day.

Comment: @MikeS. you can use "patch package" to create a patch that will be run each time tou install node_modules

Comment: @AlainIb yes, but that leads to other problems. What if you leave the project and fail to document this workaround? No it's the next person's problem. IMO, these "fixes" lead to more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 16):

Its because the port 8081 is in use..

Try

```
react-native start --port=8080
```

This will work out.

Comment: not working its stuck on Loading dependency graph . i already tried this

Answer (score 14):

Same exact problem I am facing too. I just updated to 0.59.1 and this isn't working...
As a work around, I am running the metro builder in a separate tab, and then running react in a separate tab.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

in one terminal and left it open

```
react-native run-android
```

in another terminal

Answer (score 4):

Same issue I've faced. The above solutions didn't worked for me.
The problem was from **NodeJS version**.

The installed version of NodeJS was `12.11.1` in which I got the above problems. Then I replaced with the stable version `10.16.3 LTS` and It works.

Hope this solution may helpful.

Comment: Update: This solution is no longer valid. `node 10.x` has been deprecated and no longer supported.

Answer (score 4):

### Note: Solution for iOS

Updating files in `node_modules` is not a solution. It might fix it in your machine but won't fix it for all. Every time you reinstall the modules, you need to patch it up again.

### Problem

When I ran `yarn android` the `metro bundler` successfully runs in a separate terminal and app runs with no issue.

But for `yarn ios`, app builds and opens up in simulator but the `metro-bundler` could not start so app is not running.

[image]

### Cause

What I found is, react-native uses
`packages/myapp/ios/myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:178` file to organize the sequence of action for a build.

```
            buildPhases = (
                9BD325B29C2F37E3FB2D5CCB /* [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock */,
                FD10A7F022414F080027D42C /* Start Packager */,
                13B07F871A680F5B00A75B9A /* Sources */,
                13B07F8C1A680F5B00A75B9A /* Frameworks */,
                13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A /* Resources */,
                00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC /* Bundle React Native code and images */,
                422396959450562FD5166D49 /* [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks */,
                3C714C11B606C47481E15B97 /* [CP] Copy Pods Resources */,
```

You can see that(`FD10A7F022414F080027D42C /* Start Packager */,`) metro bundler is expected to run in the beginning so that app could connect to it ASAP.

In my case, the packager could not find the metro package as my `node_modules` folder has changed location. So I needed to let it know the new location.

### How I solved? (Monorepo)

I dug deep and found the solution in `packages/myapp/ios/myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:395`

```
        FD10344022414F080027D42C /* Start Packager */ = {
            ...


            ...

            shellScript = "export RCT_METRO_PORT=\"${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081}\"\necho \"export RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}\" > \"${SRCROOT}/../../../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env\"\nif [ -z \"${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}\" ] ; then\n  if nc -w 5 -z localhost ${RCT_METRO_PORT} ; then\n    if ! curl -s \"http://localhost:${RCT_METRO_PORT}/status\" | grep -q \"packager-status:running\" ; then\n      echo \"Port ${RCT_METRO_PORT} already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly\"\n      exit 2\n    fi\n  else\n    open \"$SRCROOT/../../../node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command\" || echo \"Can't start packager automatically\"\n  fi\nfi\n";
```

you might notice that I am using `/../../../node_modules` because I have a directory structure like

```
.
└── node_modules
└── packages
    ├── common
    ├── myapp
    └── their_app
```

Its normally like this `../node_modules`

what I basically doing is maintaining two mobile apps in a single repo. See https://engineering.brigad.co/react-native-monorepos-code-sharing-f6c08172b417 for more info.

Comment: Great! This was the final piece I needed to get PNPM working with RN in a monorepo. Thanks.

Comment: I like that someone tried to figure out what is happening instead of copy-pasting or trying out random fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Adding ***android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"*** to the application tag in **AndroidManifest** work for me

```
<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
```

Comment: This got missed for us during a React Native version update. Note that this should ONLY be added to the debug variant of your AndroidManifest as you very likely do not want to allow cleartext traffic in your production builds!

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me

```
react-native start --port=8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running "yarn start" on another terminal before starting "react-native run-android"

Answer (score 1):

I just solved by watching the youtube below..
https://youtu.be/LPYez4cs5LY

I summary like below

1. make the directory

> `"android/app/src/main/assets/"`

2. replace `sharedBlacklist` variable in `node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js` like below

> ```
> var sharedBlacklist = [
>   /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
>   /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
>   /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
>   /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
> ];
> ```

with :

> ```
> var sharedBlacklist = [
>   /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
>   /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
>   /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
>   /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
> ];
> ```

3. execute command like below on the terminal

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
> index.js --bundle-output
> android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
> android/app/src/main/res

Comment: What if your `metro-config` package doesn't contain that directory or file?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just stopped Metro and tried running my app again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For `Unable to load script from assets` issue, you need to follow below steps:

```
1] Please check whether "assets" folder exists or not in 'android/app/src/main/'
    a] If it exists then, you need to delete two files(i.e. index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta)
    b] If it doesn't exist, then create the assets directory in it.

2] Use below commands from your root project directory:
    cd android
    ./gradlew clean

3] Go to the root directory and check:
    a] If there is only one file(i.e. index.js), then run below command:
        react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

    b] If there are two files(i.e index.android.js and index.ios.js), then below command:
        react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

4] Finally run below command:
    react-native run-android
```

Comment: based on ur answer its not possible to debug app

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your Users folder and delete the ".expo" directory. It might be hidden as a system directory, so view all and then delete the .expo folder.

Run npm start again.

Answer (score 0):

From the error what I understand it must run bundle command first before starting JS Server

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Finally you can check if no any dependency is missing by following command

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

then you can run android and react native server

```
react-native run-android
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution of the problem

- go to your project and run 2 command shell
- in first shell, run npm start
- in the second shell, react-native run-android

**then it will run**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u delete this line import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig in Android / MainApplication

Answer (score 0):

This is the Gradle issue.

update the **distributionURL** in **app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

**from**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

**to**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Create directory:

```
android/app/src/main/assets
```

2.- edit file project:

```
node_module\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js
```

or RN 0.64:

```
node_module\metro-config\src\defaults\exclusionList.js
```

Replace :

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

with :

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

or RN 0.64

```
var list = [/website\/node_modules\/.*/, /.*\/__tests__\/.*/];
```

with:

```
var list =  [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

3.- in folder project run this:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

4.- react-native run-android

This work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the port that is being used by React Native is not already being used.
Use the command:

> netstat -a -n -o | findstr < port >

Remember to change < port > to your React Native port.
If already have a service running in this port, you'll use this command:

> Taskkill /PID < taskPID > /F

Remember to change < taskPID > to task ID listed on previous command (it appears after LISTENING information, normaly is a 5 digit number)

After all, run npm start or react-native start again.

Answer (score 0):

try

> npm i metro-config

> npx react-native run-android