# react-native bundle not working (done but not bundle project)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm developing a react native project when i run

```
npm start -- --reset-cache

react-native run-ios
```

open a terminal `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.` and it's done 
but the simulation did not bundle project brings an older version.

I tried to delete node_modules again install and same way for pod file but it's still not working also I tried clear bundle but still not bundle my project?

any idea?

Comment: try to look at the ios simulator logs (in xcode) or run `react-native log-ios` in a separate window

Comment: @errorau try to create a brand new project ... to see if the error has to do with your react-native setup

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @MahendraThotakura first i tried -pritesh answer then it's didn't work i creted new project it worked for my case

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880251/3437900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Removes all watches and associated triggers, [link](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/watch-del-all.html).

This should work, if not then try removing watchman and reinstalling it.
Using:

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman
```

Comment: I did this but still not working packager is started when the app installed on the simulator it didn’t load bundles from the packager.

Answer (score 1):

```js
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start --reset-cache
```

You can try with above scripts whenever you want to clear all caches in your RN project