# Error In Running a React Native App : Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Image Links:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PwUH.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiaA6.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Pfx.jpg

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import navigationTheme from "./app/navigation/navigationTheme";
import navigationRef from "./app/navigation/rootNavigation";
import OfflineNotice from "./app/components/OfflineNotice";

import AuthContext from "./app/auth/context";
import authStorage from "./app/auth/storage";

export default function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    const restoreUser = async () => {
        const user = await authStorage.getUser();
        if (user) setUser(user);
    };

    if (!isReady)
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={restoreUser}
                onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
            />
        );

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            <OfflineNotice />
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} theme={navigationTheme}>
                {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
            </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default imports do not need brackets {}.
Also, you have to import AppLoading from expo-app-loading, see the documentation below: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/

To solve this change

```
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
```

to

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'
```

Hope that this helps

Comment: import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'

Comment: import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'   I did this and it showed me The Development server returned response error code: 500. I was unable to resolve module expo-app-loading from ...     so I changed to expo instead of expo-app-loading and it showed me the previous error mentioned above. I think expo-app-loading is not installed or something. Let me try.

Comment: It agve this error: AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
Error: AppLoading onError prop is required if startAsync is provided

Comment: The error is telling you what do you need: "AppLoading onError prop is required". Add the prop onError on <AppLoading onError={...} />

Comment: Pls follow the documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/, this will help you to go ahead

Comment: Pls mark as resolve if the last answer resolve the main question problem